# REST API implementation for graph data - Where to calculate graph units

Tags: rest, api-design, front-end, backend, http-response

We have a graph that shows bandwidth usage over time. The bandwidth is returned from the server in bytes.

We need to decide which units to show in the graph in case there are several different bandwidth points.

The data is received from the server like that:

```
[10000,200,3150,150,25900,193] // In bytes
```

The client shows this data in a list and in a graph.

**In the list** - convert it to KB/MB/GB based on the amount of bytes

**In the graph** - Get the highest point in bytes (25900), if it's higher than X show in KB, higher than Y shows in MB, etc...

**The question -**

Where is the right place to calculate the which units to show in the graph - in the frontend or backend rest API?

The calculation need to be made once and the user has no option to change those units.

Comment: I'd argue the front end.  If the units are well defined in the API, the front end can do whatever is needed to make sense of the data at display time.

Comment: The units to show are purely a display concern here and should be determined as close to the UI as possible. This strongly points to the frontend.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Although the decision is made once and the user has no option to change it?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, your backend should work independently of any 'clients' that might consume it. Therefore, according to your example, it would be a good idea to retrieve the needed data in raw format, and then apply the correct formatting or calculations in the clients.

Even now, you need 2 different visualizations for your data (one for the list, and another one for the charts). Therefore, in order to avoid repetition, the backend retrieves data in bytes, and you calculate stuff for the list and then for the charts.

Imagine that tomorrow you need another client (eg: a console application, for whatever reason), which needs to display data in another format (or even in bytes). You just implement the necessary calculation on the client, and everything's fine.

Here there are some principles to help understand this better, regarding layering within a project.

https://martinfowler.com/bliki/LayeringPrinciples.html

Comment: Thanks Emerson, the data is received in raw format (bytes) for the list and graph. The question is if we should pre-calculate the correct unit format to show the graph data in. The frontend already converts the list, but for the graph - a decision needs to be made about which units to show. 
If tomorrow we will need another client, the only difference will be that the client will notice that the best way to show the data in the graph is "MB" for example. The byte usage will be returned anyway.

Comment: @TheUnreal your sentence '...the client will notice the best way to show the data in the graph...'; this shouldn't be decided by the backend. The client must decide the best way to show the data. Some clients might not even have a chart to display.